# Trying to find the difference of days between two columns in two different tables using Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata, date-arithmetic

I'm trying to work in between two columns and two tables to determine the amount of days between the two so I can exclude the data that is beyond a 7 day period between the two.

For example:

- Column 1 Table 1: has a date of 01-01-2023
- Column 2 Table 2: has a date of 01-07-2023

How can I calculate the days between both of the joined tables so that I can get the number of days between the two?

I tried using this in my `select` statement:

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, fib.Purchase_Date, fid.call_date) AS difference,
```

But I get the following error message:

> [42000][3706] [Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 17.00.00.03] [Error 3706] [SQLState 42000] Syntax error: expected something between '(' and the 'DAY' keyword.

Answer (score 0):

You tagged both MySQL and Teradata, but the error is for the latter.

In Teradata, we would express the date arithmetics like so:

```
(fib.Purchase_Date - fid.call_date) DAY
```

The documentation has [plenty of examples](https://docs.teradata.com/r/Teradata-VantageTM-SQL-Date-and-Time-Functions-and-Expressions/March-2019/DateTime-and-Interval-Functions-and-Expressions/Arithmetic-Operators-and-ANSI-DateTime-and-Interval-Data-Types/Examples/Example-Calculating-the-Difference-in-Days-Between-DATE-Values).

Comment: Or if you want the difference as an INTEGER rather than INTERVAL DAY, just omit the DAY keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Teradata is not mysql and has ts own syntax see [manual](https://docs.teradata.com/r/Teradata-Database-SQL-Functions-Operators-Expressions-and-Predicates/March-2017/Aggregate-Functions/SUM/Examples?tocId=aolbdDDRrrbCxuIkBlKEkA)

```
SELECT (fid.call_date - fib.Purchase_Date) DAY;
```